# Change body background with different colors with JS

Tags: javascript

So I am new to JavaScript and I wanted to make a button that would change the body background color when pressed. But it didn't work. Here is my code. But it didn't work..

```
    function color (){
        var color = ["#02245c", "green", "blue", "red", "yellow"];
        var i;
        for (var i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
          color[i];
          document.body.style.background = color[i];
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you please add you html code?

Comment: In what way does it not work? Please provide all of the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

congrats on learning JS.

Built a solution for you, the simplest way I could think of it. Hope you like it.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

var currentColorIndex = 0;
button.onclick = () => changeColor();

function changeColor () {
  var color = ["#02245c", "green", "blue", "red", "yellow"];

  // You dont need a loop, this is what will change the color every time the function gets called.
  if( currentColorIndex < color.length - 1 ) {
    currentColorIndex++;
  } else {
    currentColorIndex = 0;
  }
  
  button.style.background = color[currentColorIndex];
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML expanding (Emmet):
  - type html:5 and press Tab;
  - type div>h1#header and press Tab;
-->
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet demonstrates that it works. It changes the document background to all the colours you provided in your snippet but only the last one (yellow) stays visible.

```js
color()

function color (){
    var color = ["#02245c", "green", "blue", "red", "yellow"];
    var i;
    for (var i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
      color[i];
      document.body.style.background = color[i];
    }
  }
```

If you want to step through them more slowly you would need to set up some kind of `setInterval()`:

```js
color();

function color (){
  let i=0, color = ["#02245c", "green", "blue", "red", "yellow"], l=color.length;
  document.body.style.background = color[i];
  setInterval(function(){
    document.body.style.background = color[++i%l];
  }, 1000)
}
```

OK, if you want to trigger it with a button-click, you can use the following snippet:

```js
((w,fn)=>{
 let i=0, color = ["#02245c", "green", "blue", "red", "yellow"], l=color.length;
 document.body.style.background = color[i];
 w[fn]=()=>document.body.style.background = color[++i%l];
})(window,'changeColor');

document.querySelector('button').onclick=changeColor;
```

```html
<button>change colour</button>
```

My last snippet might seem a bit "over-complicated". I put everything inside an IIFE (immdediately invoked function expression). This provides the necessary scope to work with a "static" variable `i` representing the current colour. This variable is only accessible from the function `changeColor()` that is defined in the same IIFE. Doing it this way keeps your global scope free from arbitrary global variables and stuff you don't really want to interfere with.

Answer (score 0):

My guess without seeing html or rest of code is that you are either missing `onclick="color()"` on your `button` element or are forgetting to register an event listener somewhere in your code.

If your button has an id of `myButton`, the your event listener can be registered like this:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#myButton');
button.addEventListener('click', color);
```

Also you don't need to declare `var i;` before your loop, it declared in the loop itself